# Assigning numbered variable names automatically

Tags: java

I will need to keep creating nodes in a tree. I would like to name them as they come up as `node1`, `node2`, `node3` etc.

I know how do this manually (say I have a `Node` class) with basic object instantiation:

```
Node node1 = new Node();
```

My question is, is it possible that if a user inputs the number of total nodes (`k`), that I can create this automatically: `node1`, `node2`, `node3`, ..., `nodek`?

Thank you for any advice; I feel like I always get stuck with this concept in JAVA, and how to find an elegant solution....

Comment: It sounds like you need an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or a [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: you can add them to a collection..

Comment: Variable names are only useful at compile time. You could add a property to the node called `name`. That would be a lot easier and more practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a collection [Read this Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

For example a `List`

Example:

```
int n= someInteger;
List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<>(n);
nodeList.add(new Node(0));
nodeList.add(new Node(1));
.
.
.
nodeList.add(new Node(n));
```

Or using a loop if you set things secuentially

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  nodeList.add(new Node());
}
```

Comment: Also another thing: writing out all those `nodeList.add(...)`s defeats the whole purpose of using a collection in the first place: I'd stick with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Variable *names* are merely a convenience for the programmer and are not even kept track of after your code is compiled. Consequently, it not possible to name variable "dynamically".

However, you can use a `Node[]` as suggested:

```
Node[] nodes = new Node[k];  // creates an array of length k

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)  // adds a new node at each index
    nodes[i] = new Node();
```

Now, your *"nodeK"* will be `nodes[k-1]`.